# Mongodb $unset leaves empty array object(javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, unset

I am using mongo "`$unset`" command to remove all matching documents for a certain criteria where index is not known.

Let's say collection looks like:-

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "list" : [
        {
            "key" : "a"
        },
        {
            "key" : "b"
        },
        {
            "key" : "c"
        }
    ]
}
```

Mongo shell command used to unset keys matching `"b":-`

```
db.test.update({"list.key":"b"}, {$unset: {'list.$.key':"b"}})
```

Result:-

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "list" : [ {"key" : "a"}, {}, {"key" : "c"} ]
}
```

Answer needed for:- How to remove the empty array object?

Note:- I have read pages suggesting to use `$pull:null`, but that doesn't fit in here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to `unset` it first and then pull the element(s) missing `key` off the array use:

```
db.test.update(
  { "_id": 1 },  // you can also use { } to clean up the whole collection
  { $pull: { "list": { "key": {$exists: false} } } }
)
```

But if there is not strong reason for this use `pull` to do it in one shot:

```
db.test.insert({ 
  "_id" : 1, 
  "list" : [ { "key": "a" }, { "key": "b" }, { "key": "c" } ] 
})
```

You can use pull to remove from the document where `list` contains a `key` with value `b`:

```
db.test.update({ 
  "list.key": "b" }, 
  { $pull: { "list": {"key": "b" } } 
})
```

This removes the respective element from the array:

```
db.test.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "list" : [ { "key" : "a" }, { "key" : "c" } ] }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both ways have worked for me, I would prefer direct $pull for one lesser operation.